# Other way to update a document in elastic search without 'id' field

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I want to updated a field in a particular document in elasticsearch collection. Is it possible to do it without the 'id' field that elasticsearch created for its documents.

tried using this.id but didn't work

```
client.update({
                index: index,
                type: '_doc',
                id: this.id,
                body: {
                    script: 'ctx._source.field = ctx._source.field + params.count_change',
                    doc: {uid: uid },
                    params: {count_change: count_change}
                }
            }, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error("Some error here",err);
                    cb(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("updated: ",res);
                    cb(null);
                }
            });
```

document having the uid same as given should update the field.

Comment: You'll need the ID to update a document, otherwise Elasticsearch won't know which document to update.  I would recommend querying for the document in one action to get the ID, and then using that ID to make updates in a second action.